# Lucene wildcard search cannot use "coord" for relevancy -- is this true?

Tags: lucene

My developer told me that Lucene cannot handle wildcard searching that employs [**coord**](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html#coord(int,%20int)) in its relevancy weightings.  We have a partial string ("begins with") logic employed so that searching with the word "wood" will bring back "wooden".

Our rankings right now are based almost entirely on [**tf**](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html#tf(float)), but I wanted to assign a weight to **coord**.  The programmer claims emphatically that Lucene, if wildcard searching like the above is enabled, completely ignores **coord** and that there is no way to add it into relevancy scoring.  Is this true?